# Automatically process received emails as plain text into a text-file each

Tags: email, thunderbird, automation

I am hoping to receive data from a webform by email. I need to process this email to extract the data in it and process it further.

I am currently using Thunderbird to receive the email and would like to find a way of exporting the data from the specific emails to a file in an existing folder. The output from right clicking on the email and saving as `.eml` file is OK, but I would like to find a method for doing this automatically.

Comment: On which OS are you working? Windows? Linux?

Comment: @rubo77 Windows 7

Comment: Did you search for a fitting Add on Already?

Comment: @rubo77 yes without success. Not saying there isn't one, just that I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Maybe you can use the filters in Thunderbird to sort these emails into a local folder?

Answer (score 0):

[FiltaQuilla add-on](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) offers (excerpted from *filter actions provided*): **Save Message as File**

The location of the file is selectable in the filter definition. The file is given an automatic name based on the subject. If a file of that name already exists in the folder, then a unique name is generated by adding a number to the end of the file name.

Comment: links seems broken. here is new link i hope correct: https://addons.thunderbird.net/de/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/

Comment: Thx @Lesmana. The link fixed…